# Angular 8 - Adding calculated value into formGroup by using formControlName

Tags: angular

I want to add Data period column calculated values into formGroup using formContolName="interval".

```
<td formContolName="interval" class="form-control">{{onlyyears(this.dynamicForm.value.tickets[i].startday,this.dynamicForm.value.tickets[i].endday)}}</td>
```

How to fetch calculated value into formControlName="interval"?
Code in below link,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-326sky?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: formcontrol need to be type input/select/etc... not TD

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to get the calculated values in formGroup

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I managed to fix this issue by the below code,
`<td><input  readonly [ngModel]="onlyyears(this.dynamicForm.value.tickets[i].startday,this.dynamicForm.value.tickets[i].endday)" formControlName="interval" /></td>`